# IGBT conduction loss

Tags: power-electronics, igbt

I want to calculate heat sink thermal resistance of IGBT using parameters from a [Datasheet.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwib_Z3t3dH1AhVAQvEDHbMRBZUQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.semikron.com%2Fdl%2Fservice-support%2Fdownloads%2Fdownload%2Fsemikron-datasheet-semix223gb12e4p-27895002.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3axKZKSwCugDpR6RCjLvwW)

To do that, I have to calculate the total power loss first. It is conduction loss + switching loss.

To calculate the conduction loss, should I use the instantaneous value of the IGBT
conduction loss

$$P_{\text{cond}}(t)= V_{\text{ce0}}(t) ⋅ I_{\text{c}}(t) + r_{\text{c}} \times i^2_{\text{c}}(t)$$

or the average loss

$$P_{\text{cond}} = V_{\text{ce0}} \times I_{\text{cavg}} + r_{\text{c}} \times I^2_{\text{crms}}$$

If it is average loss, how can I calculate the \$I_{\text{cavg}}\$ and \$I_{\text{crms}}\$ from the datasheet?

Comment: Why not use https://www.semikron.com/service-support/semisel-simulation.html

Comment: You can't calculate how much your device takes; that requires an analysis of your circuit under operating conditions.